# PrimeNG Calendar - Date displayed incorrectly

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm working with Angular and PrimeNG and I'm facing this problem: there is a form and a specific field is obtained with a calendar. When I pick the date, the format is incorrect, because the year is duplicated: i.e. 25/01/20222022 rather than 25/01/2022.

**TS**

```js
setDate(event, formControlName) {
    this.formGroup.controls[formControlName].patchValue(event);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p-calendar id="tempoAdeguamento" aria-describedby="tempoAdeguamentoHelp"
            formControlName="tempoAdeguamento" [readonly]="isReadyOnlyForm()" [showIcon]="true"
            class="esiti col-md-12 pl0 pr0" dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" [minDate]="minDate" [monthNavigator]="true"
            [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="yearRange" (onSelect)="setDate($event,'tempoAdeguamento')">
</p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PrimeNG Calendar (DateFormat section)](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12-lts/#/calendar),

> yy - year (four digit)

Hence you should **apply the date format with 'yy'** as below:

```
dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w5jtpw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. In my opinion using "yy" for a four-digit year is stupid but I've been too shallow.

Comment: Couldnt get this to work without `dataType="string"`